# How is heat transfer calculated for an aqueous salt solution?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, cooling, refrigeration

I am familiar with using $\dot{Q}=c_p\cdot\dot{m}\cdot\Delta T$ to calculate the heat transfer rate of a fluid given a singular value for specific heat capacity (such as with water), but how do I go about calculating heat transfer rate for an aequeous solution such as $MgCl_2 (aq)$? Do I somehow use the heat capacities of both water and salt together?

Comment: I'd be amazed if there's no expermintal resarch into taht. What did you find so far?

Comment: Check out solar systems - think some tried salt solutions but the disadvantage was corrosion iirc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you are quoting is for estimating the heat exchange rate of a fluid that enters a control volume with rate $\dot m$ and has a change in temperature $\Delta T$.

If you know

- the mass rate of the solution
- the precise per weight ratio of your solution
- the heat capacity of the elements
- the temperature difference

And provided there are not endothermal or exothermal reactions,  then its basically a pretty straight forward sum of the parts.

$$\dot{Q}_{total} = \dot{Q}_{water} + \sum _{i=1}^n \dot{Q}_{sub.1}   $$
$$\dot{Q}_{total} = \dot{m}_{water}c_{p,water}\Delta T  + \sum _{i=1}^n \dot{m}_{sub.i}c_{p,sub.i}\Delta T   $$

However, you will find that in most cases, because $c_p$ of water is so much greater that most other substances and the weight percentage in most solutions is much greater, you probably don't need to bother.